# What are some good resources for learning Dashcode?

Tags: xcode

What are some good resources for learning Dashcode? I've got plenty for XCode, but can neither find a good online Dashcode tutorial nor a book in stores. If anyone can help, please let me know.

My apologies if this is better suited for SO.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of resources available from the [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html) Site.

Here is a small list of stuff available:

[Dashboard Widget Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingaWidgetwithDashcode/MakingaWidgetwithDashcode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH3-SW1)

[Mobile Safari Web Application Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingaWebApp/MakingaWebApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH18-SW1)

[Starting a Project](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/WidgetProjects/WidgetProjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH4-SW1)

Comment: Thanks! But yeah I did all of these. They weren't quite as intensive as I'd like.

Comment: None of the above links is working ...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you've already checked and didn't like it or something, but the included help documentation is actually a pretty good starting point for creating simple widgets in Dashcode.  It got me through coding a couple easy ones.  Not sure if you're looking for complete beginner tutorials or something more advanced however.

Comment: Yeah I am going through the Currency Converter example again now. Yes I am actually looking for a complete beginner tutorial. I saw "Dashcode for Dummies" but it won't be out until February 2011 lol.